Angular `npm start` command failing with missing "target" from proxy.conf.json
I'm trying to use Angular's hot reloading by proxying my API layer to the the API URL. So I'm using a proxy.conf.json file at the root of my project, with the following contents.
{
  "/accounts/rest": {
    "target": "https://www.k8s.local:19443",
    "secure": false
  }
}

However, when I run npm start (which equals npm run build-themes && ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json) I receive the following error in the console:
$ npm start

> @source/accounts-client@2.4.0-SNAPSHOT start
> npm run build-themes && ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json


> @source/accounts-client@2.4.0-SNAPSHOT build-themes
> sass --no-source-map themes:src/assets

⠋ Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...An unhandled exception occurred: [HPM] Missing "target" option. Example: {target: "http://www.example.org"}
See "/private/var/folders/rk/7x0cwmtd009024nm3qdz9jxr0000gn/T/ng-hbNTSd/angular-errors.log" for further details.
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.

the full stack trace is:
[error] Error: [HPM] Missing "target" option. Example: {target: "http://www.example.org"}
    at verifyConfig (/Users/amatthews/src/WEB/accounts-client/node_modules/http-proxy-middleware/dist/configuration.js:7:15)
    at new HttpProxyMiddleware (/Users/amatthews/src/WEB/accounts-client/node_modules/http-proxy-middleware/dist/http-proxy-middleware.js:131:42)
    at createProxyMiddleware (/Users/amatthews/src/WEB/accounts-client/node_modules/http-proxy-middleware/dist/factory.js:6:28)
    at getProxyMiddleware (/Users/amatthews/src/WEB/accounts-client/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/lib/Server.js:2239:18)
    at /Users/amatthews/src/WEB/accounts-client/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/lib/Server.js:2280:12
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Server.setupMiddlewares (/Users/amatthews/src/WEB/accounts-client/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/lib/Server.js:2267:28)
    at Server.initialize (/Users/amatthews/src/WEB/accounts-client/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/lib/Server.js:1892:10)
    at Server.start (/Users/amatthews/src/WEB/accounts-client/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/lib/Server.js:3358:16)

My Angular versions are
Angular CLI: 17.3.8
Node: 20.11.1
Package Manager: npm 10.2.4
OS: darwin arm64

Angular: 17.3.11
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1703.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular   17.3.8
@angular-devkit/core            17.3.8
@angular-devkit/schematics      17.3.8
@angular/cdk                    16.2.14
@angular/cli                    17.3.8
@schematics/angular             17.3.8
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      5.4.5
zone.js                         0.14.7

When I "build" my project and run it on the https://www.k8s.local:19443 URL it works just fine, and API calls made to https://www.k8s.local:19443 resolve just fine. The problem is that the start command doesn't recognize the target. I've tried putting the proxy file in  the root of my project as well as src (and updating the proxy path). I've also tried including more options in the proxy file, like so:
{
  "/accounts/rest": {
    "target": "https://www.k8s.local:19443",
    "pathRewrite": {"^/accounts/rest" : ""},
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "headers": {
      "Connection": "keep-alive"
    }
  }
}

But that doesn't work either. I think the primary issue is that my route isn't matching the route in the proxy for some reason, but I'm not getting any debugging info, so I can't tell what's actually happening.
Thoughts?
UPDATE 1.
My npm start command runs npm run build-themes && ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json. The npm run build-themes portion of the command runs without error, so the culprit is ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json
UPDATE 2
Per the Building and serving Angular apps section of the Angular documentation if you are trying to "access a backend that is not on localhost" (which is true in my case), then you need to "set the changeOrigin option as well".
{
  "/accounts/rest": {
    "target": "https://www.k8s.local:19443",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}

I've also tried a trailing slash on "/accounts/rest", but that had no effect.
UPDATE 3
I remembered that I was working on upgrading Angular from 17 to 18, which required me to make changes to my packages. So I rolled back that code, deleted package-lock.json and my node_modules folder, then did a fresh install. And it's working now. So it appears that something in the upgraded versions is causing this issue. But I'll put that problem aside until I come back to the upgrade.

You can edit node_modules/http-proxy-middleware/dist/configuration.js:7:15 and add console.log to see what happens.

@commadelimited could you delete the src folder and share the contents of the project, so that it can be debugged. else share the replicated example on stackblitz, currently not able to reproduce.

@Naren, unfortunately I can't do that, due to some heavy confidentiality concerns.
@kemsky - I thought I'd tried that. When I console.log options I just get /accounts/rest, and not the object. When I log options.target I get undefined.

@kemsky I also logged typeof options and got string so it seems as if configuration.js is getting a string instead of the object that it is expecting.

@commadelimited please share package.json and angular.json for debugging

You are setting the secure to false but you are calling a https website so it needs to be true

@Max I tried that as well.

Have you tried setting the config file as proxyConfig in angular.json as per the documentation ? The beggining of the stacktrace is in webpack module code, you could maybe try webpack config syntax :
{
    context: ['/accounts/rest'],
    target: 'https://www.k8s.local:19443',
    secure: false,
}


I have. I've confirmed that the path is pointing to the right file by deleting / renaming the file and getting an error.

Have you tried the webpack format ?

Unfortunately the webpack didn't work either.

Maybe change the proxy format.
try this instead:
  {
    context: "/accounts/rest",
    target: "https://www.k8s.local:19443",
    secure: true
  }


Unfortunately that didn't work. I tried with secure: true within the nested block, as well as with the context, target, and secure properties loose. Neither worked.
